# Remove <div> tag from DOM

Tags: xpages

I am building an XPages application based on a custom theme I bought.
I want to use include pages to display custom 'widgets' in the header

Unfortunatelly, the included pages are rendered in a  tag, which is incompatible with the css stylesheet from the theme.

Here's the code including the pages (the idea is to make this configurable in the future)

```
<xp:panel styleClass="navbar-account">
    <ul class="account-area">
            <xp:include pageName="/nav_VisitIn.xsp"></xp:include>
            <xp:include pageName="/nav_MyVisit.xsp"></xp:include>
            <xp:include pageName="/nav_Profile.xsp"></xp:include>
    </ul>
</xp:panel>
```

The rendered html looks something like this
[image]

The css for the list item tags (and all elements below) are similar to

```
.navbar-account .account-area > li {...}
```

I want to avoid having to modify all related styles from the theme.
Is there a way to make sure the include page is rendered without the div tag or can I remove the generated div tag (but not its content) from the DOM?

Comment: Wild shot: try to set disableTheme to true

Comment: Perhaps use a xp:repeat container and build the nav bar that way.  A page will have a container -- how about trying a custom control instead of including xpages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `disableOutputTag="true"` in your `<xp:include>` tags.